# Jquery selector to get dropdown by its value

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors, selector

I cant find a way to find a dropdown with certain value.

ex1:

```
$('[value="' + $(e.currentTarget).attr('name') + '"]')
```

Gives me the option with the value.

ex2:

```
$('[value="' + $(e.currentTarget).attr('name') + '"]').parent()
```

gives me the correct drop-down. But if I have more than one `<select>` element with options with the same value I have more results.

Cannot find  `<select>` elements by its value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) can be used to target `SELECT` and for [`:selected` selector](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) for option which is selected.

> Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

```
var selects = $('select:has(option:selected[value="' + $(e.currentTarget).attr('name') + '"])');
```

```js
var v = 1;
var selects = $('select:has(option:selected[value="' + v + '"])')
selects.css('color', 'green')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
</select>
```

---

Or, Use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var selects = $('select').filter(function() {
   return $(this).val() == $(e.currentTarget).attr('name');
});
```

```js
var v = 1;
var selects = $('select').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() == 1;
});
selects.css('color', 'green')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I wnat to get the select by the value of the current selected option...not the option

Comment: sorry, not select that has an option withvalue but select that has that value selected

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos, Updated answer